# Related to Caratheodary theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-transformations

If $P$ is a set of vectors $\textbf{x}_i$'s where every $\textbf{x}_i$ is of dimension $d$ and $|P|=K$. In this case at many places I have seen that  the vectors $\textbf{x}_2-\textbf{x}_1,\textbf{x}_3-\textbf{x}_1\cdots,\textbf{x}_K-\textbf{x}_1$ are linearly dependent. This is a very crucial point in understanding the proof of Caratheodary theorem but somehow I do not understand how this (linearly dependent part) is true. I will be very thankful to you for shedding some light over it.

Here $K$ is greater than $d+1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refer to the wikipedia page of "Caratheodory's Theorem (convex hull)". They assume that $K>d+1$.

$$\left| \left\{ x_i-x_1|i=2,\ldots,K\right\}\right|>d$$

If there are more than $d$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$, they cannot be linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, is there a proof of the last statement that you wrote. I mean some easy mathematical proof

Comment: Is it another way of saying that a system of $M$ equations with $N$ unknown can not be linearly independent if $M>N$?

Comment: A homogeneous linear system with more unknown than equations has a nontrivial solution.

Comment: one other way of saying is that if there are more number of equations than unknowns then extra equations does not provide any new information about the system and hence the information provided by extra equations has to be dependent on other equations (at least one of them).